# Return true or false from sqlite transaction result

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I am using sqlite and javascript for phoneGap. I am trying get 'lookMatchEvent(...)' function's returned value(true or false) and do something by checking result in addValueToDB(..) function. but's  lookMatchEvent(...) function is not returning value immediately. Right now it's only returning false value as default. sql statements are absolutely fine, I think it's a problem with callback value. It will be great if anyone can fix this below coding.. :) thanks a lot in advance...

```
function AddValueToDB(sportName, location, dateTime, team, teamOpp) {
if(lookMatchEvent(sportName, location, dateTime, team, teamOpp)) {//adding new row to database}
else {donot add data}
}

function lookMatchEvent($sportName, $location, $dateTime, $team, $teamOpp) {
    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql("SELECT * from sport where sportName='"+$sportName+"' and location='"+$location+"' and dateTime='"+$dateTime+"' and team='"+$team+"' and teamOpp='"+$teamOpp+"';",
        [],
         function(transaction, result) {
            if (result != null && result.rows != null)
            {
                if (result.rows.length > 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        },errorHandler);
    },errorHandler,nullHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback functions run asynchronously, and a `return` returns only from *that* function.

You must split the code that should run afterwards into a separate function, and call that from the callback:

```
function AddValueToDB(sportName, location, dateTime, team, teamOpp) {
    lookMatchEvent(sportName, location, dateTime, team, teamOpp);
}

function AddValueToDB_part2(result) {
    if (result) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

function lookMatchEvent(...) {
    db.transaction(...
        ...
        function(transaction, result) {
            if (result != null && result.rows != null)
            {
                if (result.rows.length > 0) {
                    AddValueToDB_part2(false);
                }
                AddValueToDB_part2(false);
            }
            else
            {
                AddValueToDB_part2(true);
            }
        }
        ...
    );
}
```

If the `lookMatchEvent` function must not know from where it is called (because it's called from multiple places), you can give the second function as a parameter:

```
function AddValueToDB(sportName, location, dateTime, team, teamOpp) {
    lookMatchEvent(sportName, location, dateTime, team, teamOpp,
                   function(result) {
        if (result) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    });
}

function lookMatchEvent(..., my_callback) {
    db.transaction(...
        ...
        function(transaction, result) {
            if (result != null && result.rows != null)
            {
                if (result.rows.length > 0) {
                    my_callback(false);
                }
                my_callback(false);
            }
            else
            {
                my_callback(true);
            }
        }
        ...
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your callback is the problem.

```
function AddValueToDB(sportName, location, dateTime, team, teamOpp) {
    function doActionOnResult(transaction, result){
        //Do your action here
        if (result != null && result.rows != null)
        {
            if (result.rows.length > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    lookMatchEvent(sportName, location, dateTime, team, teamOpp, doActionOnResult)
}

function lookMatchEvent($sportName, $location, $dateTime, $team, $teamOpp, callback) {
    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql("SELECT * from sport where sportName='"+$sportName+"' and location='"+$location+"' and dateTime='"+$dateTime+"' and team='"+$team+"' and teamOpp='"+$teamOpp+"';",
        [],
        doActionOnResult,
        errorHandler);
    },errorHandler,nullHandler);
}
```